# Python: How to track method calls to my object from within the object?

Tags: python

I'd like to keep a list of tuples (or something similar) tracking the method calls to my object (i.e. I want to implement it within the class)
like this `(method_name, kwargs)`

What is the easiest way to do so? Is there some way, that refrains from an explicit "saving" in each implemented method?

Comment: You'll have to have all your methods call some kind of `logCall` method. You might be able to automate this using a decorator.

Comment: You can write simple method or class decorator that will capture the data you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, decorators seem to fit my needs quite well.